# Custom Button - Opens a exe file

Tags: community, custom-button

I was trying to create a custom button that opened a .net program. I would think that this could be done easily however I am running into an error.

Error: Enter a URL that is valid and well-formed

I have tried a few different ways however nothing is working using Salesforce out of the box button.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hey Brooke, it does not work like that for obvious security reasons. You can't open programs from a browser link unless you install a custom browser extension that takes care of it.

Comment: Maybe but it allows you to open a link. Which wouldnt prevent opening up say a ASP.net page or a sharepoint site

Comment: Why the down vote by the way. it was a good question.

Comment: Not from me, I agree that it is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security feature, you can't ordinarily execute random programs from your browser. However, as long as an administrator registers the program with the OS first, then it's possible. You'll want to read more about [Launching applications using custom browser protocols](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols); this is how programs like WebEx are launched from a browser link. This is really outside the scope of this site, but you should know that it involves modifying critical system files/configurations, so some care should be taken.

Even so, Salesforce URL links don't allow custom protocols. You can really only use either https or ftp. I believe in order to work around this, you'd need to execute JavaScript, so the button's code would look something like this:

```
window.top.location.href = "customhandler://program-params";
```

Your browser will ask if you want to execute the custom handler, again as a security feature, before launching the program. The button will need to be registered as an OnClick JavaScript, not a normal URL. These links/buttons will not work in Lightning, either, so you'd have to get even more complicated and write a Quick Action component.

Comment: Prefect that is exactly what i was looking for....